# Templating a Simple Boost Proto C++ Expression Evaluator

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-proto

I'd like to build on the Boost Proto "Unpacking Expressions" example from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.back_end.expression_transformation.unpacking_expressions) by using a template parameter to specify the return type of the `do_eval` transform (hitherto `double`).

For brevity I'll present a working, simplified (plus-only) version of `do_eval`:

```
struct do_eval2 : proto::callable
{
  typedef double result_type;
  template <typename X, typename Y>
  result_type operator()(proto::tag::plus, X x, Y y) const { return x + y; }
};
```

I then add a template parameter `T` instead of `double`:

```
template <typename T>
struct do_eval2 : proto::callable
{
  typedef T result_type;
  template <typename X, typename Y>
  result_type operator()(proto::tag::plus, X x, Y y) const { return x + y; }
};
```

and modify the associated `eval` structure to:

```
struct eval2
  : proto::or_<
      proto::when<proto::terminal<proto::_>, proto::_value>
    , proto::otherwise<do_eval2<double>(proto::tag_of<proto::_>(),
                                        eval2(proto::pack(proto::_))...)>
    >
{};
```

but when I use it, as shown in the code below, I get errors starting with **error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream&&’** How can I satisfy the compiler?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int one = 1, two = 2;
  cout << eval2()(phoenix::ref(one)+phoenix::ref(two)) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.back_end.expression_transformation.is_callable):

> Transforms are typically of the form proto::when< Something, R(A0,A1,...) >. The question is whether R represents a function to call or an object to construct, and the answer determines how proto::when<> evaluates the transform. proto::when<> uses the proto::is_callable<> trait to disambiguate between the two. Proto does its best to guess whether a type is callable or not, but it doesn't always get it right. It's best to know the rules Proto uses, so that you know when you need to be more explicit.
>
> For most types R, proto::is_callable checks for inheritance from proto::callable. However, if the type R is a template specialization, Proto assumes that it is not callable even if the template inherits from proto::callable.

The documentation proposes to solutions: you either wrap every invocation of `do_eval<double>` with `proto::call` or you simply specialize `is_callable` inside the boost::proto namespace and forget about the problem.

```
namespace boost { namespace proto
{
    // Tell Proto that do_eval2<> is callable
    template<typename T>
    struct is_callable<do_eval2<T> >
      : mpl::true_
    {};
}}
```

[Edit:] Here is the `proto::call` alternative:

```
struct eval2
  : proto::or_<
      proto::when<proto::terminal<proto::_>, proto::_value>
    , proto::otherwise<
        proto::call<do_eval2<double>(proto::tag_of<proto::_>(),
                                     eval2(proto::pack(proto::_))...)>>
    >
{};
```

Answer (score 4):

See the previous answer. I'd also add that another solution would be to define `do_eval2` like this:

```
template <typename T, typename D = proto::callable>
struct do_eval2 : proto::callable
{
  typedef T result_type;
  template <typename X, typename Y>
  result_type operator()(proto::tag::plus, X x, Y y) const { return x + y; }
};
```

Note the extra dummy template parameter.

EDIT: Also, in the next version of Proto, currently under development, you won't need to know about this piece of arcana, and things should Just Work. I'll be talking about it at C++Now in a few weeks.

Comment: +1 for the answer and nice to see that more Boost authors are getting active on this site!

Comment: 3 answers: you guys are spoiling me :)